# Is it possible to autocomplete codes in jupyter notebook while I programing using matplotlib in the way of object-oriented approach?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

To make it clear, I have an example:

```py
%matplotlib inline    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=[1,2,3,4]
plt.plot(a)
```

Above is an easy way to draw. When I type`plt.p` and click `Tab` in jupyter notebook, screen will show me some hints like `plt.plot` etc.

---

However, when I program in the way of object-oriented like the code below, I type `ax.p` and click `Tab` there will be no hints coming in sreen.

```py
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
```

I will appreciate it if anyone can help me!

Comment: `tab` certainly gives suggestions. Its working fine for me

Comment: Sometimes jupyter has trouble forecasting class of new variables (not sure it does that at all). Consider leaving variable initialization in a separate code block and executing it once before continuing. That'll create ax object and let jupyter see its class.

Comment: Thanks for your share, I got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type `fig, ax=plt.subplots()` followed by `ax.plot(a)` in the same cell before first evaluating `fig, ax=plt.subplots()`, jupyter will have no knowledge of what the ax object is. This is why you will not get any autocomplete hints.

For more advanced autocomplete you can use IDE's that support notebooks such as VS code (free) explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) or in [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/editing-jupyter-notebook-files.html) (paid).

You can also use TabNine or Kite for extensive autocomplete with both IDE's.

Comment: Also, [Kite](https://kite.com/integrations/) works for VS Code. And TabNine works for PyCharm/IntelliJ.